# Laravel 3 Eloquent ORM for 3 level relation & filter

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-3

I had 3 models:

**model A**:

```
class A extends \Eloquent {
    ...
    public function Bs() {
        return $this->belongsTo('B','B_id','id');
    }
    public function Xs() {
        return $this->belongsTo('X','X_id','id');
    }
    public function Ys() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Y','Y_id','id');
    }
    ...
}
```

**model B**:

```
    class B extends \Eloquent {
        ...
    public function As()
    {
            return $this->hasMany('A');
    }
        public function Cs()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('C');
    }
        ...
   }
```

**model C**:

```
 class c extends \Eloquent {
        ...
    public function Bs()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('B','B_id','id');
    }
    public function Zs()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('Z','Z_id','id');
    }
        ...
   }
```

I need all data of **A** with filters on X, Y and Z. Then I added `hasManyThrough()` to **C** like this;

**model C**:

```
    class c extends \Eloquent {
        ...
    public function Bs()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('B','B_id','id');
    }
    public function Zs()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('Z','Z_id','id');
    }
    public function As()
    {
            return $this->hasManyThrough('A','B','id','B_id');
    }
        ...
   }
```

But when I fetch the data using controller like this:

```
 public function index()
 {

 $output=C::where('Z_id','=',Input::get('Z'))
    ->with('As');
 ...
 }
```

It gives me blank out put for **As**

```
[As] => Array
      (
      }
```

*****EDIT 1******
Table Details

Here are they
**Table A** | **JobOpening** | id | title | city_id | type | company_id 
**Table B** | **Company** | id | name | websiteaddress 

Company has many Job Openings 

**Table C** | **CompanyIndustry** | id | type | company_id | industry_id 
And may be part of many Industry Sector.  
type is either 1 or 2, where 1 means primary and 2 means other 

**Table D** | **Industry** | id | name   
master table of all industry names 
eg. Service, Fashion, etc.

Comment: @eep Patel review syntax of last code lines

Comment: It has been a while since you asked and I am not sure if you found the answer or not but I noticed that, in Laravel-3 you can only use `with("eager_loading_method")` right after main model class.

so it should be like below `$output = C::with("As")->where('Z_id', "=", Input::get('Z' , '' ) );` Also it is beneficial to add default value for query Z as well

Answer (score 0):

3rd param of `hasManyThrough` is a foreign key on the close related model (`B` here), so this is what you need:

```
public function As()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('A','B','C_id','B_id');
}
```

However, as per comments, `hasManyThrough` works for `A hasOne/hasMany B, B hasOne/hasMany C` only. So in your case you can't use it.

Instead this is what you can do:

```
$c = C::where('Z_id','=',Input::get('Z'))->first();
$as = $c->b->as;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But B doesnt have C_id
The table C has foreigh key B_id which refers to id of B

Comment: Then you can't use `hasManyThrough`. It works for `A hasOne/hasMany B, B hasOne/hasMany C` only. Instead of those models, better show your tables and I'll give you correct Eloquent setup.

Comment: Added table details to Edit 1

Comment: OK, you have my suggestion already in the edit. Now just say what you want to achieve, since original issue is already solved, but your problem remains I suppose.

Comment: I want 
eg. All JobOpenings with Industry.id = 180 , JobOpenings.city_id = 2 and JobOpenings.type = "Full Time"

So basically i want to list all job openings in a city with company in selected industry sector.

Also, since industry id was also available in CompanyIndustry, i thought of directly using CompanyIndustry model.